# Pass values to json file from dockerfile while running

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a json file, for which i need to pass two keys

My file is like

```
{
  "slack_bot_token":"1234566667",
  "slack_signing_secret":"fer22324"
}
```

I need to pass these values when i run the dockerfile instead of hardcoding in my file. How can I pass the values. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tool **jq** to parse your json file.

Or convert json to env file for Docker